# Dagger-android share dependencies between Activities

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I'm using [dagger-android](https://google.github.io/dagger/android) for DI. There're a few common dependencies I want to provide to **every Activity**. They depend on an Activity class but don't relay on a certain Activity implementation. Like this:

```
class NavigatorImpl(private val activity: Activity) : Navigator {..}
```

Now I have to write the same code at every ActivityModule:

```
@Module
class SomeActivityModule {

    @Provides
    fun navigator(activity: SomeActivity): Navigator = NavigatorImpl(activity)

    // some deps...

}

@Module
class AnotherActivityModule {

    @Provides
    fun navigator(activity: AnotherActivity): Navigator = NavigatorImpl(activity)

    // another deps...

}
```

I tried to provide these dependencies via `AndroidSupportInjectionModule` but it turns out that Dagger generates separate Submodules for each Activity, and we can access to an Activity dependency only at the certain modules (`SomeActivityModule` and `AnotherActivityModule` at this example):

```
@Module(includes = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class])
interface AppInjectionModule {

    @PerActivity
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [SomeActivityModule::class])
    fun someActivity(): SomeActivity

    @PerActivity
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [AnotherActivityModule::class])
    fun anotherActivity(): AnotherActivity

    // we don't have any Activity in the graph -> throws an error
    @PerActivity
    @Provides
    fun navigator(navigator: NavigatorImpl): Navigator

}
```

So how can I provide such dependencies without duplicating code in every ActivityModule?

Comment: Does It have to be the same instance of the dependency or different instances?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque different instances. Every time a new Activity Subcomponent is initialized it must create and provide a new instance of `NavigatorImpl` with the aforementioned Activity provided as a dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you put all of your common things into a module that you can reuse. (Also please use constructor injection with `@Binds` as shown below

```
class Navigator @Inject constructor(activity : Activity) { /* ... */ }

@Module
interface BaseActivityModule {

    @Binds
    fun navigator(navigator: NavigatorImpl): Navigator

    // other bindings...

}
```

Then you have to switch to custom subcomponent declarations instead of `@ContributesAndroidInjector`. There is a [related open issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/961), but for now you have to write the boilerplate.

You declare an `AndroidInjector.Factory` that binds everything you need, then you use this for your subcomponent builder instead of the default `AndroidInjector.Builder`.

```
object MyCustomInjector {

  abstract class ActivityBuilder<T : Activity> : AndroidInjector.Factory<T> {
    override fun create(instance: T): AndroidInjector<T> {
      seedInstance(instance)
      activity(instance)
      return build()
    }

    @BindsInstance
    abstract fun seedInstance(instance: T)

    @BindsInstance
    abstract fun activity(instance: Activity)

    abstract fun build(): AndroidInjector<T>
  }
}

@Module(subcomponents = [(SomeActivityModule.SomeActivitySubcomponent::class)])
abstract class SomeActivityModule {

  @Binds
  @IntoMap
  @ActivityKey(SomeActivity::class)
  internal abstract fun contributeSomeActivity(builder: SomeActivitySubcomponent.Builder): AndroidInjector.Factory<out Activity>

  @PerActivity
  @Subcomponent(modules = [BaseActivityModule::class])
  interface SomeActivityActivitySubcomponent : AndroidInjector<SomeActivity> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder : MyCustomInjector.ActivityBuilder<SomeActivity>()
  }
}
```

Your subcomponent builder thus binds both `SomeActivity` and `Activity`, and your subcomponent includes the `BaseActivityModule` with the bindings defined above.

For more information you can also have a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49072558/1837367) with a few more steps...

Comment: It works, but imo it's much easier to provide an Activity's super class (that is used in `BaseActvityModule`) in every Activity module directly (`@Binds fun superActivity(someActivity: SomeActivity): Activity`). We still have to write some boilerplate, but it's 1 line instead writing a Subcomponent & Builder

Comment: is it possible to inject as dependency of ViewModel, using constructor injection? For generating the ViewModelFactory I am using dagger